# How to show Next and Previous slides besides the current slide with views slideshow module?

Tags: views, javascript

I'm trying to build a slideshow for my website using "views slideshow" similar with the below image:

[image]

I don't know how to make previous and next "slides, titles and count numbers" visible!
It seems It's not possible to make it happen with views slide show settings. may be with some function prepossessing or something It's possible but unfortunately I don't have that knowledge.
Would you please help me to figure this out!!

Comment: check this http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/drupal-theme-previous-next-pause-and-resume-controls-views-slideshow

Comment: thanks bala, this is not what i want. I can change the look and the text of default "previous and next" control options with CSS but what I really need is rendering previous and next slides as you can see in the picture. Thanks